How to only enable GCP Identity Platform user once email is confirmed?

I registered a user using firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword, however I require the email to be confirmed, before Enabling the user.
I am confused how to realise this simple "double opt-in" flow. I've enabled Allow passwordless login in the Email / Password provider logins, but no email is sent. If I read https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links it would appear I need to implement sendCustomPasswordResetEmail myself?
I perhaps wrongly assume GCP Identity Platform could send the emails?

There is no difference between Firebase Authentication and Google Cloud Identity Platform in this respect. I linked a few questions where this was covered before.

And specifically for sending mail, I have to use some third party or something, is that right?

I see there is an inbuilt email sending via firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
